# No se inserta nada en base de datos mysql workbench con sentencia SQL en FastApi

Tags: python, mysql, sql, api

estoy intentando capturar datos desde un csv y luego de esto insertarlos (o actualizarlos) en una base de datos MYSQL Workbench , ocupando la siguiente sentencia en crudo.

```
session: Session = Depends(get_db)  ---> capturo bdd.
portabilidad_msisdn y final_id ---> datos que necesito del csv.

session.execute(("INSERT INTO portabilidad (msisdn,operator_id) VALUES ({}, {}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operator_id={}").format(portabilidad_msisdn, final_id, final_id))
```

Mi problema reside en que funciona el programa pero por alguna razon no agrega ningun dato a la Base de datos. Ayuda por favor.

(No adjunto codigo, porque no es problema de codigo, mas bien es de logica. No entiendo bien porque no se aplica esa sentencia si le programa corre bien.)

Comment: El problema de hecho si podría ser de código. En módulos como sqlite3, si no se especifica que sea automático, es necesario hacer `[el objeto que representa la conexion].commit()` para enviar los cambios a la base de datos. No se nada sobre el modulo que usas, pero quizá es necesario también para este caso.

Comment: @DanteS. Muchas Gracias Dante, era simplemente eso.

Comment: De nada Matias c:

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO.

Simplemente tuve que agregar `session.commit()` para aplicar los cambios.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.